# Add slideshow function to gallery using Jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, html, gallery, slideshow

What I would like to achieve is a button on toggle that will trigger an automatic slideshow. Like a play/pause button.

I'm using an image gallery from html5up.net the template is here:

https://html5up.net/lens

The next image is currently triggered on click with:

```
<div class="nav-next"></div>
```

Within the HTML the gallery appears as so, and clicking a thumb will activate the appropriate image.

```
<section id="thumbnails">
<article>
<a class="thumbnail" href="images/fulls/114.png">
<img src="images/thumbs/114.jpg"/></a>
</article>

<article>
<a class="thumbnail" href="images/fulls/116.png">
<img src="images/thumbs/116.jpg"/></a>
</article>

<article>
<a class="thumbnail" href="images/fulls/168.png">
<img src="images/thumbs/168.jpg"/></a>
</article>
</section>
```

I'm trying variations of attempts as such:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('.thumbnail');
    var $next = $active.next();    

    $next.addClass('active');

    $active.removeClass('active');
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

However have only achieved frustration at this point as I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's a minimal version of the gallery if you want to experiment:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWwVqd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the slideshow function like so:

```
$(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.nav-next').trigger('click');
        }, 7000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jQuery Plugin on your page head?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using Jquery for other functions.

Comment: Have you tried to look on your console if there is any error/s?

Comment: I have the error "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'" Do you see the issue with the Jquery code above? I'm still learning as far as syntax is concerned.

Comment: `$(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
    var $active = $('.thumbnail');
    var $next = $active.next();    

    $next.addClass('active');

    $active.removeClass('active');
}, 5000 );
});`

Can you try this?

Comment: Well, that fixed the error so thanks, unfortunately the function still doesn't work.

Comment: I've just discovered adding the active class to the thumbnail doesn't actually change the main image either, so I'm pretty much back to the drawing board. If you have any ideas I'm all ears.

Comment: It's because you put quotations " on your function which js consider it as String. For function try putting "<a>" tags outside the article.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but that would require restructuring the website and css quite a bit. I'm pursuing creating a .click event on <div class="nav-next"></div> every X seconds at the moment as I think that may be a better solution to what I've already tried.

Comment: Goodluck bro. I'm not pro about jQuery. Just sharing my knowledge and way on how to solve things. Have fun!

Comment: I really appreciate the help, so thanks a lot for the advice, bro.